# How do I print with jt400?

Tags: java, printing, ibm-midrange, jt400

Is it possible to print though as400 using jt400 library?

Would i need to create a spool file on the as400 and then release it to the printer?

Can anyone just point me in the right direction, there aren't many resources on google

So far I could only retrieve the list of printer connected to as400 and get their properties using `com.ibm.as400.access.ISeriesPrinter` class

Comment: Just for the record: I was so happy to see that someone has asked the same question 2 years earlier and then realised it was myself. Well played past me, well played

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I expect an open and write to a Printer File (PRTF) then close, with possibly one or either of a stream or record-level-access write method, just like a HLL program running local to the server, should function quite the same.

But there are specific features available from the Toolbox.  Rather than web searching, although not the best results, searching the IBM i KnowledgeCenter [formerly InfoCenter] can assist; e.g. the following was found when searching on terms **Toolbox** and **printer** [albeit only older release docs were presented; so the links are likely to go defunct within a couple years, though I expect searching newer releases will find something similar or equivalent]:

[IBM i 6.1->Programming->Java->IBM Toolbox for Java->IBM Toolbox for Java classes->Access classes->Print classes](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzahh/print.htm)

From that link can be found there examples:
[Example: Creating spooled files](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzahh/npexamplecreatesplf.htm#npexamplecreatesplf)

[Example: Creating SCS spooled files](http://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/ssw_ibm_i_61/rzahh/npexamplecreatescssplf.htm#npexamplecreatescssplf)